# Visualisation libraries - AJAX, Flex, Flash, HTML, C/C++

Tags: mysql, ajax, statistics, visualization, analysis

Okay guys - simple question. I have some data in a MySQL database that I want to visualise. Now some methods for doing this are:

[Axiis](http://www.axiis.org/)

[GetPivot](http://www.getpivot.com/)

[ManyEyes](http://manyeyes.alphaworks.ibm.com/manyeyes/)

Are there any others?

Max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash:

1. [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/)

JavaScript

1. [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)
2. [Processingjs](http://processingjs.org/)
3. [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)

C/C++

1. [GTK](http://www.vtk.org/)

Here is a [nice commercial tool](http://www.tableausoftware.com/).  Here are some other [fun tools](http://insideria.com/2009/12/28-rich-data-visualization-too.html).

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at [QtSQL](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/sql-model.html) too.